# 502 Bad Gateway error thrown in AKS nginx ingress after redirect back from external service

Tags: azure-aks, nginx-ingress, .net-6.0

We have a working Azure Kubernetes Service cluster with dotnet 6.0 web app.  The pods are running on port 80 but the public url is running behind https cert which is being  handled by an nginx ingress controller with cert secret.  All this is working well.

We are adding some new functionality (integration from an external service). When signing into our app, with this new functionality, there's a brief redirect to the external service page.  Once the user requests have completed, the external service redirects back to our site using a preconfigured redirect url to which is posted some data (custom header and query string).  At this point, our site errors with 502 bad gateway.

When i review the logs on the nginx ingress controller pod, i can see some additional errors:

[error] 664#664: *17279861 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.240.0.5, server: www-dev.application.com, request: "GET /details/c2beac1c-b220-45fa-8fd5-08da12dced76/Success?id=ID-MJCX43A4FJ032551T752200W&token=EC-0G826951TM357702S&SenderID=4FHGRLJDXPXUU HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://10.244.1.66:80/details/c2beac1c-b220-45fa-8fd5-08da12dced76/Success?id=ID-MJCX43A4FJ032551T752200W&token=EC-0G826951TM357702S&SenderID=4FHGRLJDXPXUU", host: "www-dev.application.com", referrer: "https://www.external.service.com/"

10.244.1.66 is the internal ip of one of the application pods.

at first i thought this was an error related to annotations:

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"

because the referrer is an https:// site making the request.  However adding that annotation makes the site unusuable (probably because the dotnet app pods are listening on port 80).

```html
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: application-web
  namespace: application
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true" 
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - www-dev.application.com
    secretName: application-ingress-tls
  rules:
  - host: www-dev.application.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: applicationwebsvc
            port: 
              number: 80
```

Here's the application ingress yaml.

Anyway, does anyone have any idea what the problem could be here?  thanks

Comment: Is there any way anyone can think of that i can to troubleshoot the root of this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a resource limits issue.  There was one particular request that was causing memory usage to spike.  This cause the container to be OOMKilled.  This is what was leading to the 502 Bad gateway error message (because when it was killed, the container was no longer there to service the request).

Answer (score 0):

Ingress class moved from annotation to ingressClassName field, also you do not need to specify https before. Can you please try this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: application-web
  namespace: application
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true" 
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - www-dev.application.com
    secretName: application-ingress-tls
  rules:
  - host: www-dev.application.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: applicationwebsvc
            port: 
              number: 80
```

Please also check to ingress [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress).

Comment: my bad Phillip, my yaml shouldn't have the https:// for the hostname.  i've corrected that in the post

Comment: ok i'll move the className and see what the impact is. However, why do you think this would result in a 502 error (and note not all requests result in that status.  It's only those with a specfic callback/redirect url)

Comment: yes..wrong incgressclass will result in 502

Comment: cool - i'm testing it now.

Comment: no. same error unfortunately.  that doesn't appear to may any difference.  I have checked the deployed yaml that it has changed so that ingressClassName appears under the spec statement

Comment: ok, but now your ingress manifest is at least correct. can you check if the error message changed?

Comment: yes, i checked that.  No the error is identical to what it was before